# How can I change the default calendar for Cortana?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar, samsung-galaxy-s7

When I use voice command for Cortana to add an event to my calendar, it defaults to the wrong Google account calendar.  I have to manually switch to the correct calendar each time.

- I'm signed in to Cortana with the correct account, which is a "Microsoft" account using my primary Google email address.
- I have gone to "Manage Calendars" on my device and 'turned off' the calendar for the other account.
- I have cleared the cache & data for the Cortana app and signed back in with the correct account.

I do not want to remove the other Google account from the phone completely, as I still use it (primarily for YouTube and games), but I do not use that account's calendar for anything ever.  I have no clue why Cortana insists on using it or even knows it exists.

**Device details:**

- SAMSUNG-SM-930V (Galaxy S7)
- Android v6.0.1
- Rooted

Comment: I believe you need to contact Microsoft for this..